# Arithmetic progression and summation.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

Had this question from some exam which goes like so:

> Let $V_r$ denote the sum of first $r$ terms of an arithmetic progression whose first term is $r$ and the common difference is $(2r-1)$. Let $T_r = V_{r+1} - V_{r}$ and $Q_r = T_{r+1}-T_r$ for $r=1,   2, 3 \cdots$
>
> The sum $V_1 +V_2 + \cdots + V_n$ is?
>
> Answer: $\frac{1}{12}n(n+1)(3n^2+n+2)$ (just writing so you could know the terms the answer is in)

My line of reasoning was this:
For any given AP, I generalized a formula for the calculation of sum of sums of terms, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}S_i =\frac{n(n+1)}{6} (3a+nd-d)$

Where $a, n$ and $ d$ have their usual meanings.
So I figured it is just the same thing, plug in values, and get the answer but after a while, I realized that

> Let $V_r$ denote the sum of first "$r$" terms of an arithmetic progression whose first term is "$r$"

This r has a unique condition to it so I could not use what I just derived. Could someone help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach for this question is straightforward
First express $V_r$ as sum of an AP ,then sum up
For $$V(r) a=r   d= 2r -1 n= r$$
$$V(r) = (r/2)*[2r + (r-1)(2r-1)]$$
which simplifies to
$$V(r) = (1/2)(2r^3-r^2+r)$$
now use standard summation formulas to get
$$∑V(r) = (1/2){(2)[n^2*(n+1)^2/4] -(1/6)(n)(n+1)(2n+1) +(1/2)(n)(n+1)}$$
which simplifies to
$$∑V(r) = (1/12)(n)(n+1)(3n^2 +n+2)$$

Answer (score 1):

This just means that $a$ and $n$ are both $r$ in your formula, and $d=2r-1$.  An example of a progression that qualifies is $3,8,13$ because it starts with $3$, has $3$ terms, and has difference $5=2\cdot 3-1$.  Another is $4,11,18,25$

Comment: How do I accommodate this fact in the formula?

Comment: You just replace $a$ by $n$ and $d$ by $2n-1$ in the formula.  It should come out to the given answer, but it doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: It doesn't come out to be that answer...